# Déchiffrer le mot « B.... intentions » dans un texte manuscrit ?

Tags: sens, synonymes

[image]

> **Le vali a protesté de ses boivres intentions, mais j'ai...**

Est-ce que ce mot est **boivres** et si oui, quel en est le sens et y a-t-il des synonymes, car je pense que ça n'existe pas en français moderne...

C'est qu'à mon avis le contexte de l'extrait qui suit, qui dit « **J'ai écrit d'autre part dans ce sens au sultan, et j'ai obtenu de Sa Hautesse qu'elle envoyât des ordres au Vali afin de faire revenir celui-ci sur ses décisions précédentes (interdiction des fruits etc).** », prouverait qu'il ne s'agit pas de « bonnes » intentions.

[image]

Comment: Pardon the edit to your question -- I only just now noticed your last line. The parenthesis is "Interdiction des fruits etc." (and this is the edit I introduced). Note that an older meaning of "et cetera" was not just "et ainsi de suite" pour remplacer d'autres exemples mais "et entendre ici le reste de la phrase", donc ce n'est pas probablement tous les fruits qui sont interdits mais des fruits d'un certain genre.

Comment: J'ai enlevé le tag "ancien français" car ce texte n'a aucun contenu d'ancien français, c'est du français moderne.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je pense que le mot est "bonnes", ce qui donnerait: "Le vali a protesté de ses bonnes intentions, mais j'ai...".
Ce qui a tout à fait du sens.

Comment: Agreed. The dot is probably a slip of the pen.

Comment: I don't agree with you, I'll send another passage talking about the inverse.

Comment: j'ai ajouté un autre passage pour clarifier le sens un peu.

Comment: Je n'en vois rien qui rendrait invalide « bonnes intentions ». Le vali va recevoir des ordres pour lui faire "rethink" ses décisions précédentes — ce qui sont donc pas idéales. En tout cas c'est des bonnes intentions dont on proteste, non ? Peux-tu clarifier un peu ?

Comment: @Abdelhafid Le passage ajouté ne clarifie en rien, et c'est clairement écrit bonnes, les deux "n" du mot sont très nets et faits comme les autres "n" de ce texte.

Comment: merci pour les commentaires. réponse acceptée.